# Firefox development - how to disable the guides or scrollbars while interacting with elements in the inspector?

Tags: firefox

Whilst using the Firefox inspector, hovering over particular elements (with no rhyme or reason on which elements) will trigger the Firefox scrollbar to show.

Is there a way to either disable the guides (I assume this is the cause) or to stop the scrollbars from appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This, to my knowledge, is not possible. I am sorry about this.

And also the inspecting of the code does highlight what it does. With the exception of JavaScript source code